# Polymer - Slow animation core-scaffold

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

On my site, infinitech.org/beta, on mobile devices, pulling out the menu has EXTREME lag.  Closing this menu also causes severe lag.  I'm using a `core-scaffold`.  Can anyone think of what's causing this?  I'm using Polymer 0.5.4.  Thanks!﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you solved this problem? Have the same issue. Drawer opens very slowly while main screen blinking grey and black. In browser it's ok but on Nexus5 it always reproduces.

UPD. I have found problem.
You should go to bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.css
And delete "opacity: 0;" for element #scrim. Works perfectly!

Comment: My problem was that the `img` size was too large (almost 1MB!).  I used compressor.io and fixed it :D